# Can't Access File in Resources Folder

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm trying to load an image that I have stored in my /src/main/resources folder. When I do, however, I keep running into a NullPointerException that stems from the resource not being found.

Here is the code snippet:

```
        try {
            String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bern.png").toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
```

Here is an image of my project file tree:

[image: An image of my project file tree]

And here is an image of my target build file tree:

[image: An image of my target build file tree]

Here is the NullPointerException stacktrace: 
https://pastebin.com/KqJVxWEL

I have tried using pretty well every possible path for the image file that I can think of. (/src/main/resources/bern.png, src/main/resources/bern.png, /bern.png, etc.).

I have also tried using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` instead of `getClass().getResource()`. From what I understand, the only difference between the `Class` and `ClassLoader` version of `getResource()` is that the `Class` version is not inherently absolute relative to the root, whereas the `ClassLoader` version is.

When I run `getClass().getResource("").toPath()`, I get the path that leads to the `classes` directory. This aligns with what I've read about the `getResource()` method working with the target build file tree. However, I don't see the resources folder showing up anywhere in the target build; I think that's the core of my problem. I'm just not sure how to fix it.

I know this question has been asked numerous times before, but the answers to the other version of this question haven't helped me out much.

I'm using NetBeans 11, and this project is running on the Maven build system. I haven't done much work with Maven in the past, so forgive me if this problem is extremely easy to fix.

Anyone know how I'm approaching this wrong?

EDIT: The problem is not anything with my project structure or code as shown by the code compiling correctly when run using `mvn` via the command line. As a result, it's an issue with NetBeans specifically and the way that it is viewing the resources folder.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, that's unfortunately still leading to a NullPointerException with both the `ClassLoader` and `Class` methods.

Comment: Have you checked and followed https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/?

Comment: Re _"a NullPointerException that stems from the resource not being found"_ , post the stack trace that matches the code you have posted.

Comment: @skomisa, added, though I'm not sure how much it elucidates.

Comment: @pmverma, I have, yes. Unfortunately didn't help me figure this out. :(

Comment: I don't see `bern.png` anywhere in the target directory.

Comment: @user207421, yeah, I think that's the core of my problem. Do you know why my resources folder isn't coming over to the target directory?

Comment: Re _"'I'm not sure how much it elucidates"_, it states the line on which the NullPointerException occurred. The stack trace shows that the NullPointerException is occurring on line 66 of **Mainframe,java** in **<init>**, the instance initialization method. So what is the content of that line?

Comment: @skomisa, line 66 is the assignment of `path` to the output of `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("bern.png").toString()`. Edited my code example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the resource contents as a Stream (instead of the URL or file path)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bern.png");
        BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(testImage);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still running into an error. If I pass `in` into `ImageIO.read()`, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: input == null`. Still not finding the resource for some reason.

Comment: That's really odd. The above code executed fine for me. Are you running your code using netbean? Or using a maven plugin?

Comment: I'm running it using NetBeans, yeah. Did you create the resources folder by just clicking on the `Source Packages` node and adding a new Folder? Or did you do it some other way?

Comment: In the interest of of debugging, Can you run your your program after building .jar?Also, try running ```mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.exampe.Main"  ```.

Comment: The resources folder icon looks like a source folder icon, which might be confusing you IDE. (Not a netbeans user so I cannot make specific suggestions about folder types). Try running your code from the command line via  the mvn commands (posted above). If your code works there, yon can conclude the IDE is at fault and debug in that direction.  In my case maven created the resource folder automatically since I specified an archetype.

Comment: running it using `mvn` worked! I hadn't thought of running it directly without the IDE. Thank you for the advice! I'll create another question specific to NetBeans to see if I can find out how to properly create a resources directory. Thanks again!